# What do you call these cars ridden by disabled people?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call these cars used by disabled people, they are everywhere and I've seen them again today and was wondering what they are called; these cars they are very small for a person to sit on used by the disabled for traveling on the sidewalk instead of walking?

Comment: Electromobiles?

Comment: @skymninge Actually I shouldn't of call it a car, their small like a wheelchair, but powered.

Comment: That's what I would call an electromobile. More like an electric wheelchair, often with a basket attached on front, so like a powered vespa, kind of.

Comment: They're hoverboards with the optional chair attachment. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK they're called mobility scooters.

Comment: I like the Dutch Scootmobiel :)

Answer (score 5):

The lighter duty devices are often called *[mobility scooters](http://www.electric-wheelchairs-101.com/Mobility-Scooters.htm?ref=catname)* or just *scooters* in the US. They fit under the broader category of *electric wheelchairs*.

Comment: You may also hear brand names, such as Rascal, Hoveround, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Power chair, electric wheelchair, etc.  (But not "electric chair" please... that means something else.)
[image: PC]

scooter, electric scooter, mobility vehicle, etc.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about [electric wheelchairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorized_wheelchair), also known as powerchairs, EPWs or motorized wheelchairs.

In addition to those names, they are also often called by whatever name their brand is - one example would be "Amigo".